# how to plot stack bar chart from table dataset

Tags: r

```
> mytable
   Var1 Home Work
1    10  523  196
2    11  395  155
3    12  829  330
4    13  680  282
5    24 2897 1210
6    35 4689 1950
7    46 1291  567
8    47 1099  465
9    48 1681  764
10   59 1962  821
```

[image]

I created the stack bar chart in Excel.
How to create the same chart in R?

i tried the ggplot or the based function, but not work

Comment: Try `mytable |> pivot_longer(-Var1) |> ggplot(aes(name, value, fill = factor(Var1))) + geom_col()`, i.e. reshape your data to long format first.

Comment: Without any further processing, you can get what you want with `barplot(as.matrix(mytable[c("Home","Work")]))` . The key change to make is that `barplot` needs a `table` or `matrix` object, not a `data.frame`. It also might be nice to choose a non-grey palette - `barplot(as.matrix(mytable[c("Home","Work")]), col=palette.colors(palette="Tableau 10"))`

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function on the data you are using and pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg